# Assigning styles with Javascript vs assigning styles in the server-side script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working in a project which uses rather obsolete technology. During the work I've encountered this problem. Since I cannot find any oficial W3 recomendations, I've decided to ask the question here.

Imagine a simple dinamically-generated table, like this:

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr id="row1"><!-- More content here --></tr>
    <tr id="row2"><!-- More content here --></tr>
    ...
    <tr id="rowN"><!-- More content here --></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

The job I want to do is deceively simple: Assign to each table row one of two CSS style classes, let's call them `.evenRow` and `.oddRow`.

The problem is: Let's assume these classes are defined in an external CSS style sheet. I am not allowed to modify that file, yet I am obliged to assign one of these classes to every table row. I cannot use any CSS tools like Less, Sass or Compass. Just pure CSS + Javascript/jQuery + a server-side scripting language.

I've found 3 possible solutions to the problem, yet since I lack web programming experience I don't really know which one would be the best one in terms of "good web developing practice".

1.
Copying CSS styling from the external stylesheet to our file and assigning simple CSS3 rules like:

```
    table tr:nth-child(even) { copied .even property:value pairs }
    table tr:nth-child(odd) { copied .odd property:value pairs }
```

**Cons:** What we're doing is really to replicate CSS rules with no reference to the external stylesheet. In the event of changing the external stylesheet, we'll need to manually modify the rules in our document. To make the things worse, this won't work in IE8 (we are obliged to support this version).

2.
Assigning classes with Javascript:

```
    jQuery("table tr:even").addClass("oddRow") 
    jQuery("table tr:odd").addClass("evenRow")
```

**Doubts:** Is it really correct to leave the preparation of the HTML/CSS to the client side? Is it considered a good practice to execute such operations as class assigning by Javascript? I mean, we can tell the right class when the document is generated, before sending it to the client. There is no reason to wait with that.

3.
Assigning classes on the server side. 
For example, to define a counter within the loop that takes care of generating all the TR elements. If the counter value is even, assign `evenRow` class and the other way round, thus incrementing the counter in every loop iteration.

**Doubts:** Once again: Is it considered a good practice to assign a CSS class/properties using a server-side language? Depending on the language, it can leave in a code a little mess or a great mess. In addition, I don't really find it intuitive to let the server-side language taking care of the presentation layer...

So, my question is: Are there any official recommendations on that case? Can any of these solutions be considered "the only right solution" or a "never-ever apply this solution"?

I'm rather new to front-end developing, so please have mercy on me with your answers ;)

Comment: what is your server side backend, are you using any templating solutions?

Comment: We use JSP, with very few taglibs, mostly scriptlets. (I know --_--, I told you it is a rather obsolete technology).

Comment: Well, then that's your answer, use jsp for this.

Comment: Using JSP is what I mean as a 3rd solution in my case. I listed my doubts ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSP is meant for presentation, so I don't really understand your doubts about using it for what it's meant for. Just don't write scriptlets in new code, use JSTL instead.

The other two "solutions" are IMHO poor workarounds at best, for the mentioned reasons.